# Wicket - Inter-session communication or Create new Request(Cycle) manually

Tags: request, wicket

I have some wicket panel store in a static Hashmap from different sessions, i want to do some like if some panel notifies the map, then the map notifies all other panel. 
for example:

```java
public class PanelMap{
    private static Map<Long, List<MyPanel>> map = new HashMap<Long, List<MyPanel>>();

public static void subscribe(Long id, MyPanel panel){
        if (!map.containsKey(id)){
            map.put(id, new ArrayList<MyPanel>());
        }
        map.get(id).add(panel);
    }
}

public static void notify(Long id, String notification){
        if (map.containsKey(id)){
            List<MyPanel> panels = map.get(id);
            for(MyPanel panel : panels){
                panel.newNotification(notification);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Panel, newNotification(String notification) i want to send request to server and refresh my panel in browser.

```java
public void String newNotification(String notification){
   // do some business logic depends on notification
   onMyRequest();
}
```

i've made some search among wicket behavior source files and about i found in `AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior` i tried to make my own onRequest method inside my wicket panel as follows

```java
private void onMyRequest(){
    AjaxRequestTarget target = ((WebApplication)getApplication()).newAjaxRequestTarget(getPage());
        target.add( _some_wicket_components_ );

        RequestCycle.get().scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(target);
    }
```

but all i did is some Ajax error in Wicket Ajax Debug about

```
 Wicket.Ajax.Call.processComponent: Component with id _containerdiv_ was not found while trying to perform markup update.
ERROR: Cannot find element with id: _someComponentIdOnPanel_
```

(those components are exist)

How could i send my own request to server (or how can i get valid AjaxRequestTarget to update my components? )

**Update:** I need inter-session communication.

Comment: does the `_some_wicket_components_` exists in the in html page?

Comment: yes, it does, it's basically an WebMarkupContainer, content container (<div/>)

Comment: Is there are reason you're not using the wicket event bus?

Comment: only reason is i don't know what is it :) what is it for? some principal, guide or link ? please

Comment: https://www.google.pl/search?q=wicket+intercomponent+events When it comes to your error in your AJAX Debug Window you probably have a component which is initially hidden and then you show it. You need to set on it `setOutputMarkupIdPlaceholderTag(true)`

Comment: the problem is, the component ART wants to refresh is in other session. clearly doesn't find, but i don't know how to update panels across sessions

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by 'Intersession communication'? My session affecting the session of another user or my session affecting another of my sessions (how and why would I get multiple sessions?)? Obviously you can't add another users panels to my AjaxRequestTarget. To do this you'd need some kind of push technology like Atmosphere or you'd have to wait until the other user creates an AjaxRequestTarget of his own (maybe using a TimedUpdatingBehaviour.

Comment: i mean one of user has logged in, seeing his panel, and another user has logged in too, and if user#2 send notification, user1's panel need to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update panels on different user's sessions, you obviously can't use the current AjaxRequestTarget as this in a way represents a single communication between the server and the requesting user of which another user's Browser has no way of knowing. (Very very basically spoken)

You could either use [an AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior.html) to poll for updates. This would generate new AjaxRequestTarget for every user at regular intervals that you can use to attach changed panels to. It's a very basic and simple implementation that will most likely impact your systems performance and generate quite some traffic.

The other way would be to use something like [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere), which is supported by Wicket-Atmosphere (quickstart can be found [here](https://github.com/papegaaij/wicket-atmosphere-quickstart)) and has some examples over at the [wicket-library.com](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/atmosphere/?1), but that's all I know about this.

Comment: i don't want to use AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior, but wicket Atmosphere sounds good. Honestly three days trying to revive an simple 'hello-world' example. i can't configure web.xml & atmosphere.xml but i'm still fighting

Comment: @Victor that doesn't sound so good, but all I know about Atmosphere is that I saw it on the wicket changelog. Maybe this would warrant a new question on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Use Wicket event bus system. Have a look to the "Wicket events infrastructure" chapter of the [free Wicket guide](https://code.google.com/p/wicket-guide/).

First you need to create one class to encapsulate the notification and the `AjaxRequestTarget` and pass them using the events infrastructure.

```
private class Notification {
    private String message;
    private AjaxRequestTarget target;

    ... constructor, getters, setters...
}
```

Then the panels that want to recive the event have to override `onEvent` method, something like this:

```
public void onEvent(IEvent<?> event) {
    if (event.getPayload() instanceof Notification) {
        Notification notification = (Notification) event.getPayload();

        ... do whatever you want before updating the panel ...

        // Update the panel 
        notification.getTarget().add(this);

    }
}
```

All the components will recive all the events that are send using Wicket events infrastructure. So you can send the event from any other panel using one method like this

```
protected void sendMessage(String message, AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    send(getSession(), Broadcast.BREADTH, new Notification(message, target));
}
```

Remember that if you want to update the components using AJAX, you need to set `setOutputMarkupId(true)`. And if it's a component that can be hidden and you want to make it visible using AJAX, then you need to set `setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true)`.

Comment: Ok, then use Session as the IEventSink instead of getPage(). I'm going to update the sendMessage method.

Comment: sounds great, i'll check it after i arrived home around 18:00 CEST UTC/GMT +2

Comment: Did you mean sessions of differents users? If so, then I misunderstood and the answer below is the good one.